Qual atributo usar para upload de arquivo em java
Estou desenvolvendo um projeto particular para aprender mais java e estou em duvida em como criar um atributo onde vou guardar arquivos no meu banco de dados.

Não duplique perguntas, se precisar comentar ou explicar melhor o problema, faça na pergunta original.
